# Можно ли так построить фразу?

Tags: стилистика

"Необходимо направить работника для прохождения медосмотра".

Обычно направляют куда-то или есть и такой вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В канцелярском стиле возможно, это клише.Направить куда? для чего? - управление двунаправленное. Только куда? иногда (когда и так понятно куда)опускается для краткости: Например, в КОАП :

"... следует обращать внимание на основания, по которым вы должны были быть направлены для его прохождения. 
Согласно Постановлению № 475 к врачу вас могут направить для прохождения медицинского освидетельствования только в случае:... 
         "http://qqdps.ru/koap_rf_12_26.html

Есть даже "Направление ДЛЯ ОСМОТРА" Именно так и пишут.Или: Для прохождения осмотра работника можно направить в любое медицинское учреждение, при условии что у последнего есть необходимая лицензия.

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, лучше будет "направить на медосмотр" или, корявее, "на прохождение медосмотра". А "для" тут никаким боком.